# How can I have arbitrary content inside an ng-repeat with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ordered list of items that I want to be displayed. Getting this done with Angular is trivial:

```
<p>Filter a game: <input type="text" ng-model="search.name" /></p>
<game-card ng-repeat="game in games | filter:search" game ="game" size="large"></game-card>
```

This outputs an ordered list of games that has been sorted from the database. **However, I want to show a few snippets of arbitrary content inside this `ng-repeat`.** This diagram below indicates what I'm after. The lefthand side shows how it should look in the unfiltered state, the righthand side if a search term as present.

[image]

As you can see, I want to highlight the first item with a "Next up" heading, and following that, an "After that" heading. When a search is present, I don't want these headings at all as they won't be relevant.

I'm completely new to Angular ("you lost me at service" new, by the way), but have come from a Knockout.js background. What is the "Angular way" of solving this?

Stack up `ng-if`'s on the headings and compare with `$index`? Does `$index` even care about the filter being applied?

Comment: How you are going to decide the heading of your elment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to `ng-show` the titles only if the length of the results passed through the filter equaled the total number of games:

```
<h2 ng-show="games.indexOf(game) == 1  && search.length == games.length">More Games</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of dirty solution: within the `ng-repeat`ed element, put something like

```
<div ng-if="$index === 0">
  <h2>Next up</h2>
</div>
<div ng-if="$index === 1">
  <h2>After that</h2>
</div>
<div>
  <!-- Your content goes here, unconditionally -->
</div>
```

And the obvious problem with this is that two tests are performed for each "instantiation" of the content of the `ng-repeat`ed element, and they are useless except for the first and second.

Otherwise you could place your first two bits of contents with headers *outside* the ng-repeat and then start repeating from index 2, but I'm not sure that's possible with `ng-repeat`.

If it's not, then split your data into `firstElement`, `secondElement` and `rest` where `rest` is `Array.prototype.slice.call(/* your initial list of elements */, 2)`.

The problem with this last solution is that it requires you to adapt your data to how you present it, which is undesirable for obvious reasons.

**edit:** OK here's something better, not tested:

```
<div ng-if="elements.length > 0">
  <h2>Next up</h2>
  <div><!-- First content goes here, it uses elements[0] --></div>
</div>
<div ng-if="elements.length > 1">
  <h2>After that</h2>
  <div><!-- Second content goes here, it uses elements[1] --></div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="element in elements.slice(2)">
  <!-- The rest goes here, unconditionally -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing your ng-repeat in the `game-card` tag, do it in a wrapping `div` and then use [ng-repeat special variables](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/T38E301214-Understanding-ng-repeat-special-variables-.html):

```
<p>Filter a game: <input type="text" ng-model="search.name" /></p>
<div ng-repeat="game in games | filter:search">
  <div ng-if="$first">NEXT UP</div>
  <div ng-if="$index === 1">AFTER THAT</div>
  <game-card game="game" size="large"></game-card>
</div>
```